# AceFEM: Why SMTShowMesh doesn't show changes in initial configuration?

Tags: finite-element-method, postprocessing, acegen

I am changing initial positions of nodes after the analysis has been initialized (after the `SMTAnalysis[...]`) and this procedure works fine, but the problem is that change is not shown in postprocessing. How can I get SMTShowMesh to plot modified version of initial configuration?

The following is a small example to illustrate the problem.

```
<< AceFEM`;
(* A small test analysis with 1 element. *)
Clear[testAnalysis]

testAnalysis[] := (
  SMTInputData[];
  SMTAddDomain["test","OL:SEPEQ1DFHYQ1NeoHooke",{"E *"->1000.,"\[Nu] *"->0.3}];
  SMTAddMesh[{{0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}},{"test" ->{{1,2,4,3}}}];
  SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{{1, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}, {2, 2 -> 0}}];
  SMTAddNaturalBoundary[{4, 2 -> -1}];
  SMTAnalysis[];
  );
```

We call the analysis function, see the initial configuration and print initial coordinates of all 4 nodes.

```
testAnalysis[]
SMTNodeData["X"]
SMTShowMesh[ImageSize->100,"BoundaryConditions"->True,"Marks"->"NodeNumber"]
(*{{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {0., 1.}, {1., 1.}}*)
```

[image: one element]

New values of initial coordinates are calculated (rotation of domain for 45 degrees).

```
newCoordinates = RotationTransform[Pi/4, {0.5, 0.5}] /@ SMTNodeData["X"]
(* {{0.5, -0.207107}, {1.20711, 0.5}, {-0.207107, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.20711}} *)
```

New coordinates are assigned to nodes and print of coordinates reflects that.

```
SMTNodeData["X", newCoordinates];
SMTNodeData["X"]
(* {{0.5, -0.207107}, {1.20711, 0.5}, {-0.207107, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.20711}} *)
```

Plotting of mesh does not show the change of initial coordinates. I expect to see element rotated for 45 degrees.

```
SMTShowMesh[ImageSize->100,"BoundaryConditions"->True,"Marks"->"NodeNumber"]
```

[image: one element problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AceFEM stores and uses also list`SMTNodes` which is constructed after `SMTAnalysis[]` command. It seems to not be changed automaticaly when you assign new coordinates to `SMTNodeData["X", newCoordinates]`. If you assign the coordinates to `SMTNodes` manualy (2nd and 3rd positions store X and Y coordinates of each point, so do not overwrite the 1st and 4th positions) as

```
SMTNodes[[;; , 2 ;; 3]] = newCoordinates;
```

then `SMTShowMesh` takes the required coordinates:

```
SMTShowMesh[ImageSize -> 100, "BoundaryConditions" -> True, "Marks" -> "NodeNumber"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found an alternative solution with the undocumented function `SMTUpdatePostData`. Apparently it works according to its name, it updates postprocessing data that has been modified after calling `SMTAnalysis`.

```
SMTUpdatePostData[]
SMTShowMesh[ImageSize -> 100, "BoundaryConditions" -> True]
```

[image: rotated element]